# Infinite loop : Process not terminating properly

Tags: infinite-loop, binary-search-tree

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

int secondlargest(struct node* a)
{
    while(a->right != NULL){
        secondlargest(a->right);
    }
    return a->data;
}
```

I am not able to trace where have I done the mistake and why its not coming out of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on the recursive version, change the while to if.

```
int secondlargest(node* a)
{
    if(a == null){
        // if the first node is already NULL
        return -1;
    }
    if(a->right == NULL){
        return a->data;
    }else{
        return secondlargest(a->right);
    }
}
```

Basics of recursion:

- Must have base case
- Break down problem size recursively

If you want the iterative way:

```
int secondlargest(node* a)
{
    node* temp = a;
    int data = -1;
    while(temp != null){
        data = temp->data;
        temp = temp->right;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: typically i test the a == null before calling the method, it makes the method more clean and avoid this test for future calls that i know it will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you shouldn't use an while but instead an if because it is recursive, but what do you want the function to return? the data of the last member? if so it should be like this:

```
int secondlargest(struct node* a) {
   if(a == NULL) return -1;
   secondlargestr(a);
}

int secondlargestr(struct node* a) {
   if(a->right!=NULL) return secondlargest(a->right);
   return (a->data);
}
```